# I try to scrape data from url's using following code,it displays an error message:

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from array import array
import csv
url = ['http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA1.html', 'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA1y.html', 'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA2.html', 'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA2y.html', 'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA3.html']

 data = []
 m = 0
for i in range(1,len(url)):
if m<url[i]:
page = urlopen(i)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
name_box = soup.find("pre")
name = name_box.text.strip()

f = open('output.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'Filename:', name  
f.close()
```

The message `IndentationError: expected an indented block.` is displayed for for the "if" statement.

Comment: Is this your code or there is a typo? The `if` inside `for` and next lines inside `if` is not properly indented.

Comment: I'm a newbie and I'm not able to find the proper syntax for using both these  statements

Comment: Changing the position of open and close statements worked for me. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to indent the blocks after the `for` statement, and `if` statement.

Try the code below:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from array import array
import csv

url = [
    'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA1.html',
    'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA1y.html',
    'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA2.html',
    'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA2y.html',
    'http://cura.free.fr/gauq/902gdA3.html'
]

data = []
m = 0
for i in range(1,len(url)):
    if m<url[i]:
        page = urlopen(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        name_box = soup.find("pre")
        name = name_box.text.strip()

f = open('output.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'Filename:', name
f.close()
```

---

As @kuro suggested, you might wanna change the position of the sentences that open and close file. If your purpose is to capture all the text within pre tags in the given URLs, the code below will do that for you.

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')    
data = []
m = 0
for i in range(1,len(url)):
    if m<url[i]:
        page = urlopen(i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        name_box = soup.find("pre")
        name = name_box.text.strip()
        print >> f, 'Filename:', name


f.close()
```

Comment: I think the `print` statement must also be inside `if` statement. Otherwise only one value will be written in file. For that case `open` and `close` statement position have to be changed

Comment: @kuro Agree. Edited the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I re write the code as:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'w')

for i in url:

    page = urlopen(i)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    name_box = soup.find("pre")
    name = name_box.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    print >> f, 'Filename:', name


f.close()
```

It worked for me.